# Convergence/divergence of the limit of a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

In order to prove asymptotic normality of the time series OLS estimator (this context is not important), I have done the following:

Assumptions:

• $\mathrm{var}\left(y_{t}\right)=\gamma_{0}\quad\forall  t$

• $ \mathrm{cov}\left(y_{t},y_{t-j}\right)=\gamma_{j}\in\mathbb{R}^{k}\quad\forall j$

• $\underset{j\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\mathrm{cov}\left(y_{t},y_{t-j}\right)=\gamma_{j}=0$

• ${\sum}\left|\gamma_{j}\right|<\infty$

Then:

$$\begin{align}
L&= \underset{{\scriptstyle T\rightarrow\infty}}{\lim}\mathrm{\mathrm{var}}\left(\sqrt{T}\left(T^{-1}\sum_{t}y_{t}-\mu\right)\right) \\
&= \underset{{\scriptstyle T\rightarrow\infty}}{\lim}\mathrm{\mathrm{var}}\left(T^{-1/2}\sum_{t}y_{t}\right) \\ 
&=\underset{{\scriptstyle T\rightarrow\infty}}{\lim}T^{-1}\mathrm{\mathrm{var}}\left(\sum_{t}y_{t}\right) \\
&=\underset{{\scriptstyle T\rightarrow\infty}}{\lim}T^{-1}\sum_{t}\sum_{s}\mathrm{cov}\left(y_{t},y_{s}\right) \\ &=\underset{{\scriptstyle T\rightarrow\infty}}{\lim}T^{-1}\left[T\cdot\gamma_{0}+2\cdot\left(T-1\right)\cdot\gamma_{1}+2\cdot\left(T-2\right)\cdot\gamma_{2}+...+2\cdot\gamma_{T-1}\right] \\
&=\underset{{\scriptstyle T\rightarrow\infty}}{\lim}T^{-1}\left[T\gamma_{0}+2\sum_{1\leq j\leq T-1}\left(T-j\right)\gamma_{j}\right] \\
&=\underset{{\scriptstyle T\rightarrow\infty}}{\lim}\gamma_{0}+2\sum_{1\leq j\leq T-1}\left(1-\dfrac{j}{T}\right)\gamma_{j}
\end{align}$$
I'm assuming the last step equals:
$\gamma_{0}+2\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\gamma_{j}$

since concluding from here is rather easy. The problem being that I do not think it's the case, since j also converges to infinity.

Am I wrong? If so, why?

Comment: It's definitely true if $\sum j\gamma_j$ converges.

Comment: Said sum converges (as $\sum{|\gamma_{j}|}$ does), as assumed. Could you please expose why?

Comment: The sum does not necessarily converge. Take $\gamma_j = 1/j^2$ . (In this case it your statement is true anyway).

Comment: If you just multiply out the terms, you get $2(\sum\gamma_j \gamma_j - T^{-1}\sum j\gamma_j)$, so all you need is that $T^{-1}\sum j\gamma_j = 0$.

Comment: So what you really need is that $\sum j\gamma_j$ is asymptotically less than $T$.

Comment: Assuming $\gamma_j = j^p$, it is true if $p< -1$ which is true since the sum $\sum |\gamma_j| < \infty$.

Comment: I think you need a little more stronger condition to prove normality. With the given hypothesis I feel we will not be able to prove although I don't have counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after a long battle with this one I think what you have written is true. Note that, since $\sum|\gamma_j|$ converges, we can find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$
\sum_{j=N}^T j| \gamma_j| \leq \sum_{j=N}^T j \frac cj = cT \;\;\;\; \forall c\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}.
$$

This gives that

$$
\lim_{T\to \infty}T^{-1}\sum_{j=N}^T j |\gamma_j| \leq c\;\;\;\; \forall c\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\},
$$

which implies that

$$
\lim_{T\to \infty}T^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^T j |\gamma_j| = 0.
$$

Finally,

$$
\underset{{\scriptstyle T\rightarrow\infty}}{\lim}\gamma_{0}+2\sum_{1\leq j\leq T-1}\left(1-\dfrac{j}{T}\right)\gamma_{j} = {\lim_{T\to\infty}}\gamma_{0}+2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\gamma_j - 2T^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^\infty j\gamma_j \\
={\lim_{T\to\infty}}\gamma_{0}+2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\gamma_j
$$

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Notice that you meant that c is non-zero, if you want to edit.

Comment: Yes thank you. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Can you explain how did you get your first inequality. Thanks

Comment: @chandu1729 I edited my answer to fix up some details. Since the series $\sum |\gamma_j|$ converges, its tail is less than any constant $c$ times the tail of the harmonic series (which diverges).

Comment: But how does that imply your inequality. Its not clear. I feel your arguments are wrong. Please be more rigorous